# Ошибка importScripts is not defined при создании PWA

Tags: javascript, битрикс, pwa, service-worker

Есть сайт на 1с Битрикс, разрабатываю для него PWA. В корне проекта создал manifest.json, pwabuilder-sw-register.js, pwabuilder-sw.js

При запуске сайта на главной странице появляются следующие ошибки:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
Uncaught ReferenceError: importScripts is not defined
A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost/') with script ('http://localhost/sw.js'): A bad HTTP response code (404) was received when fetching the script.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответственно такие же ошибки в "проде" на котором https. Но при этом сам workbox отправляет сообщения в консоль.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В header.php подключил manifest.json и прописал скрипт для PWA

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">

<script type="module" data-skip-moving="true">
    import 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@pwabuilder/pwaupdate';
    const el = document.createElement('pwa-update');
    document.body.appendChild(el);
</script>
```

В footer.php прописал скрипт для serviceWorker и подключил файлы serviceWorker

```
<script>
    void 0 !== navigator.serviceWorker && navigator.serviceWorker.register("sw.js")
</script>
<script src="/pwabuilder-sw-register.js"></script>
<script src="/pwabuilder-sw.js"></script>
```

Само приложение сделано в отдельной папке /mobile-myclub/. Приложение можно скачать с сайта, всё работает.

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "background_color": "#DE2A1B",
  "description": "Описание",
  "dir": "ltr",
  "display": "standalone",
  "name": "My club",
  "orientation": "portrait-primary",
  "scope": "/mobile-myclub/",
  "short_name": "My club",
  "start_url": "/mobile-myclub/",
  "theme_color": "#ffffff",
  "categories": ["magazines"],
  "screenshots": [
    {
      "src": "windows11/Wide310x150Logo.scale-200.png",
      "sizes": "620x300"
    }
  ],
  "icons": [Подключаем иконки],
  "shortcuts": []
}
```

**pwabuilder-sw-register.js**

```
import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@pwabuilder/pwaupdate";
const el = document.createElement("pwa-update");
document.body.appendChild(el);
```

**pwabuilder-sw.js**

```
const CACHE = "pwabuilder-offline-page";

importScripts(
  "https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/5.1.2/workbox-sw.js"
);

const offlineFallbackPage = "offline.html";

self.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  if (event.data && event.data.type === "SKIP_WAITING") {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});

self.addEventListener("install", async (event) => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE).then((cache) => cache.add(offlineFallbackPage))
  );
});

if (workbox.navigationPreload.isSupported()) {
  workbox.navigationPreload.enable();
}

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp("/*"),
  new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: CACHE,
  })
);

self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
  if (event.request.mode === "navigate") {
    event.respondWith(
      (async () => {
        try {
          const preloadResp = await event.preloadResponse;

          if (preloadResp) {
            return preloadResp;
          }

          const networkResp = await fetch(event.request);
          return networkResp;
        } catch (error) {
          const cache = await caches.open(CACHE);
          const cachedResp = await cache.match(offlineFallbackPage);
          return cachedResp;
        }
      })()
    );
  }
});
```

Пробовал загружать библиотеку Workbox в Service Worker скрипт и подгружать локально, но тогда начинал жаловаться на использование workbox. Также пробовал использовать fetch для загрузки скрипта.

**Вопрос**

Как исправить ошибку подключения importScripts is not defined?
Битрикс не умеет импортировать файлы js?

Comment: Публикуйте описание ошибок текстом, а не скриншотами. Текст ошибки "Cannot use import statement outside a module" сообщает Вам, что имеется попытка использовать import вне модуля, что мы и наблюдаем в подключаемом скрипте pwabuilder-sw-register.js. importScripts либо используется/вызывается раньше чем загружается библиотека, либо вообще не загружается.